gpg 2.2.24, gpg: public key decryption failed: Permission denied gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
recently upgraded to gpg 2.2.24 version
Error:
gpg: public key decryption failed: Permission denied
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
gpg --list-secret-key is listing all the secret keys from /opt/eventapi/.gnupg/pubring.gpg.
Question: How to load the gpg passphrase via gpg-agent --allow-preset-passphrase in gpg 2.2.24 ?
Earlier gpg 2.0.20, a passphrase has to be entered to decrypt a file using the secret key
Its done via the below script using the gpg agent preset>
#!/bin/sh
RUNAS_USER=usr
GPG_PASSPHRASE_BIN_PATH=/usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase
[[ "$RUNAS_USER" != "$(id --user --name)" ]] && { echo 'Aborting, not the expected RUNAS_USER.'; exit 1; }
# will only run as usr
killall --user "$RUNAS_USER" gpg-agent 1>/dev/null 2>&1
sleep 2
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon --allow-preset-passphrase --max-cache-ttl 63115200 > ~/.gnupg/.env_vars.txt)
source ~/.gnupg/.env_vars.txt
ps xuf
read -p 'Enter >> PASS  << of the GPG passphrase :' -s PASS; echo
echo; echo
GPG_PASS="$PASS"
echo "$GPG_PASS" | "$GPG_PASSPHRASE_BIN_PATH" --preset XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX # sec
echo "$GPG_PASS" | "$GPG_PASSPHRASE_BIN_PATH" --preset XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX # ssb

# Do a test-decryption
md5=$(gpg --batch --quiet --decrypt EncryptedTestFile.gpg | md5sum --tag | sed -n -e 's/^.*= //p')

if [ 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' == "$md5" ]
then
  echo "Decryption test OK"
else
  echo "Error decrypting testfile, try running this script again"
fi

But running the same script is resulting as below
gpg: public key decryption failed: Permission denied
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
Even after entering the password manually via xterm is not solving the issue permanently.
How to do the gpg-agent preset as above in gpg 2.2.24
Updated: Upon further investigation , the
"gpg-agent --daemon --allow-preset-passphrase" is not working as it is working in gpg 2.0.20
